# Latkes with applesauce

Tags: halacha, blessing, chanuka, ikar-tofel

If one eats a *latke* with applesauce should he make a *bracha* on the applesauce (is the applesauce considered *tafel* to the *latke* ? )

Comment: I cant imagine the applesauce being the ikkur

Comment: In most cases, both the latkes and the applesauce get the same bracha - *shehakol*. Thus, it wouldn't matter. Unless you have chunky applesauce.

Comment: @DanF Latkes are probably HaAdama, unless you're using pureed packaged potato-food to make them. But then who wants to eat them anyway?

Comment: @DoubleAA My understanding (I could be wrong) is that unless the potatoes are "visible" as potatoes, it's shehakol. Most people I know, say *shehakol* on potato kugel (perhaps, there are different minhagim). Latkes are essentially made the same way as kugel except kugel is baked, latkes are fried. Those "potato buds" or what I call summer camp potatoes are ugly. I consider it "chometzdik" potato starch. I might as well use my left-over Pesach potato starch.

Comment: @DanF it depends if it's shredded or not. If it is then it's *ha'adamah*; if not, *shehakol*.

Comment: How do you know the oil isn't the ikkar? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Brachot.org [writes](http://berachot.org/halacha/09_ikar.html):

> The tofel item needs to be eaten along with the Ikar.[Shaar HaTzion 212:21, Vezot HaBracha (pg 89). Even though the Laws of Brachos (pg 209) seems to argue on this, it clear from his examples and footnote that he's not arguing but just is using different terms than the Shaar HaTzion.] For example, apple sauce with latkes would be considered tofel and wouldn't require its own bracha. If there is leftover applesauce it does not require another Bracha, however, if one takes more applesauce it will require a Bracha.[Halachos of Brachos (pg 59-60)]